# How to resolve error CS0433: The type 'type' exists both in 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml,...' and 'Microsoft.UI...'

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, winui-3

I'm making a UWP Windows app in C# using WinUI 3.0 and a few days ago I started getting this kind of error:

```
CS0433  The type 'NavigationView' exists in both 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime' and 'Microsoft.UI, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'
```

This is the snippet from the auto generated code that causes the error:

```
[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler"," 0.0.0.0")]
        private global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationView settingsNavPane;
```

Until now, I solved instances of this issue by deleting `/bin` and `/obj`'s contents, but the problem seems to persist.

I'm aware this is a compiler error, so I tried adding a reference to the .csproj file:

```xml
<References>
  <Reference Include="Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll"/>
</References>
```

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but this didn't solve the problem either. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you specific `XamlControlsResources` as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls in app.xaml file?

Comment: Nope, I haven't

Comment: Please try add above and tell me the result.

Comment: I tried this and it works, thank you :D could you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from your error, it looks you have not specific `XamlControlsResources`, please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui2/getting-started) and add XamlControlsResources in your app.xaml file.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer after version 7 and greater produceS this problem. Downgrading the version to 6.014 fixed the issue for me.